# Directly interact with file in git server

Tags: git

My scenario in the java application is

1. Finding all file has name test.txt in remote repository (have some file that has the same name in other path)
2. Check whether a string is contained in that file

It quite easy to do that if we sync the source from remote repo to local repo. But is there any way to do that directly in remote repo
(Assume the project is quite large, i dont want to download it to my computer by git init)

Comment: With `master repository`, do you mean the origin master repository (`origin/master`)? If not, the question is a bit unclear to what you mean exactly.

Comment: Sorry im new in git.Yes, it is remote repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean "remote" when you say "master repo".

Since you didn't mention how your origin is hosted (just a bare repo on a file share? github? gitlab? TFS? ...): the general answer is "no".  The design of git is that you perform source control operations locally, using a handful of commands (like `fetch` and `push`) to sync with remote repos as needed.

Some options for server hosting software provide web API interfaces, which may or may not allow you to do what you want remotely - though to tell the truth, I'm not aware of any that would allow quite that much remote interaction in anything resembling an efficient manner.